# Unable to preselect values in multiple select in angular

Tags: angular, html, select, angular-ngmodel

Cannot able to preselect values even-though [selectedModels] list are populated with [same objects] from [options] list.

```
 <select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedModels" class="col-md-7 form-control">
      <option [ngValue]="obj" [selected]="checkIfSelected(obj)" *ngFor="let obj of options">{{obj.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Tried by using [selected] aswell but cannot able to succeed. 'checkIfSelected' method is returning correct boolean values.

Looking for quick help. Thanks!!

After loading selectedModels list from service call, changing the objects from options list

```
this.selectedModels.forEach(sm => {
      sm = this.options.find(o => o.id == sm.id);
})
```

Comment: Can you show how are you populating the `selectModels` property?

Comment: Updated my question @Jota.Toledo

Comment: Ill add an answer in a while, give me some mins

Comment: Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the fact that you are trying to set the *reference variable* **inside of** the `forEach` method, which wont have an effect in the array being iterated.

This would be the case *if* you would set *individual members of the reference variable*, but that would leave you with 2 different objects, what would inevitably break the select functionality.

The simplest way to solve your issue (keep track of the selected objects + update selected objects when options are loaded) would be to go with an immutable approach by changing:

```
this.selectedModels.forEach(sm => {
      sm = this.options.find(o => o.id == sm.id);
})
```

To

```
const nextSelected = this.options
  .filter(option => this.selectedModels.some(selected => selected.id === option.id)
this.selectedModels = nextSelected;
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaax17) for a set of examples showcasing my answer.